# CSS and JavaScript Transition Translation Jumpy

Tags: javascript, css

The transition of my header and navigation finish in the desired places and have the correct look I am going for, however, the transition is jumpy, almost as if something is trying to restrict the translation from happening. Any advice on how I can go about fixing this erratic transition behavior?

With a similar problem, the padding of the initial element style was the problem (before JavaScript changed the style class.)

I expect the transition to be smooth and seamless, not fighting to transition into it's proper end place.

Thanks again for any help.

PS: I'm not sure how to reference the JS file at the bottom of the HTML code to allow the JS code snippet to change the html elements properly. The CSS which is supposed to make the 'headerLogoBackground' sticky at the very top of the window and change is not being applied which is needed to answer the question. However, I don't have this problem on my local machine - sorry guys, working on fixing this in the stackoverflow code snippet editor:/

```js
// JavaScript
window.onscroll = function() {
  headerSlide_and_change();
}; // end window.onscroll

function headerSlide_and_change() {
  if (document.body.scollTop > 30 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {
    // vars
    var headerLogoBackground = document.getElementById("headerLogoBackground");
    var headerLogo = document.getElementById("headerLogo");
    headerLogoBackground.classList.remove("headerLogoBackground"); // header background
    headerLogoBackground.classList.add("headerLogoBackGroundTransform");
    headerLogo.classList.add("headerMove"); //header title slide
  } else {
    /*---header background---*/
    var headerLogoBackground = document.getElementById("headerLogoBackground");
    headerLogoBackground.classList.remove("headerLogoBackGroundTransform");
    headerLogoBackground.classList.add("headerLogoBackground");
    /*---header---*/
    var headerLogo = document.getElementById("headerLogo");
    headerLogo.classList.remove("headerMove");
    headerLogo.classList.add("headerLogo");
  } // end else
} // end navChangeOnScrollUp
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vw;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #796651;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

// Initial CSS 
// header
.headerLogoBackground {
  background-color: none;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.headerLogo {
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.headerLogo a {
  font-family: 'Squada One', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d8cfc3;
}

.headerLogo a:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: darkslategrey;
}

// navigation bar
.navRaise {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: static;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.navUlStyle {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 8%;
  padding-left: 12.5%;
  padding-right: 12.5%;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Squada One', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d8cfc3;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

// JavaScript CSS Classes used to change initial CSS 
.headerLogoBackGroundTransform {
  /* to replace 'headerLogoBackground' */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white !important;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  z-index: 10;
}

.headerMove { /* to replace 'headerLogo' */
  margin-block-start: 0;
  transform: translate(-10%, 0px) !important;
  transition: transform .2s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script|Squada+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div id="Welcome"><!--Wrapper div-->
    <!-------------------------Top Section------------------------->
    <header id="headerLogoBackground" class="headerLogoBackground">
      <!--header-->
      <h1 id="headerLogo" class="headerLogo"><a id="headerLogoLink" href="index.html">Lorem Dolo</a></h1>
      <!--navigation-->
      <nav id="navRaise" class="navRaise">
        <ul id="navUl" class="navUlStyle">
          <li><a id="topNav" title="Top" href="#Welcome"> Top </a></li>
          <li><a id="servicesNav" title="Services" href="#Services"> Services </a></li>
          <li><a id="contactNav" title="Contact" href="#Contact"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div><!-- end wrapper div -->
  <!------------------------JavaScript Documents--------------------------->
  <!-- I don't think path to external JavaScript file is relevant for stackoverflow code snippet -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use passive event listeners for the scroll handler.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I'll definitely use it in the future.